# Single-quote part of a line using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Convert input text as follows, using `sed` or `awk`:

Input file:

```
       113259740 QA Test in progress
       219919630 UAT Test in progress
```

Expected output:

```
       113259740 'QA Test in progress'
       219919630 'UAT Test in progress'
```

Comment: What did you try?  Could you have a file containing `12345 A word or two 23445`? If so, where do the quotes go?  What about `12A34 A word 33 times 2014-03-25 23-MAR-2015`?  If so, where do the quotes go?  What are the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this GNU `sed` command also,

```
sed -r "s/^( +) ([0-9]+) (.*)$/\1 \2 '\3'/g" file
```

- `^( +)`, catches one or more spaces at the starting and stored it in a group(1).
- `([0-9]+)` - After catching one or more spaces at the starting, next it matches a space after that and fetch all the numbers that are next to that space then store it in a group(2).
- `(.*)$` - Fetch all the characters that are next to  numbers upto the last character and then store it in a group(3).
- All the fetched groups are rearranged in the replacement part according to the desired output.

**Example:**

```
$ cat ccc
       113259740 QA Test in progress
       219919630 UAT Test in progress

$ sed -r "s/^( +) ([0-9]+) (.*)$/\1 \2 '\3'/g" ccc
       113259740 'QA Test in progress'
       219919630 'UAT Test in progress'
```

Comment: Yep and I have posted according to the op's input.

Comment: Due to the `-r` option, this solution requires _GNU_ `sed`. Also, at least 2 leading spaces are assumed. Replacing `( +) ` with `( *)` and `\1 \2` with `\1\2` would deal with _any_ amount of leading spaces. Since the _entire_ line is being matched, there is no point in using the `g` option.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It's a perfectly fine solution. I'm just stating the unstated prerequisites and constraints.

Comment: did you want my solution to be like this `sed "s/^\( *\) \([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)$/\1 \2 '\3'/g" file`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You're welcome; the only thing I think _should_ be changed is to remove the superfluous `g` flag; the rest - with the prerequisites stated - is fine. If you really want a POSIX-compliant solution (one that uses neither `-r` nor `-E` for extended regexes), I was thinking of this: `sed "s/^\( *\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\) \(.*\)$/\1\2 '\3'/" file` - note how you cannot use `\+` and must instead emulate it with `\{1,\}`; _with_ `-r`, my thought was this: `sed -r "s/^( *)([0-9]+) (.*)$/\1\2 '\3'/" file`. In both cases you'll match - and preserve - _any_ amount of leading spaces, including none.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `sed` or BSD (OSX) `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/^( *)([^ ]+)( +)(.*)$/\1\2\3'\4'/" file
```

- `^( *)` captures all leading spaces, if any
- `([^ ]+)` captures the 1st field (a run of non-space characters of at least length 1)
- `( +)` captures the space(s) after the first field
- `(.*)$` matches the rest of the line, whatever it may be
- `\1\2\3'\4'` replaces each (matching) input line with the captured leading spaces, followed by the 1st field, followed by the captured first inter-field space(s), followed by the single-quoted remainder of the input line. To discard the leading spaces, simply omit `\1`.

Note:

- Matching the 1st field is more permissive than strictly required in that it matches *any* non-space sequence of characters, not just digits (as in the sample input data).
- A *generalized solution* supporting *other forms of whitespace* (such as tabs), including after the 1st field, would look like this:

  ```
  sed -E "s/^([[:space:]]*)([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]+)(.*)$/\1\2\3'\4'/" file
  ```

---

If your `sed` version doesn't support `-E` (or `-r`) to enable support for *extended* regexes, try the following, POSIX-compliant variant that uses a *basic* regex:

```
 sed "s/^\( *\)\([^ ]\{1,\}\)\( \{1,\}\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3'\4'/" file
```

Comment: @user3347931: See my update; what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

And in `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s '"'"'", $1; for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i; print $NF "'"'"'" }' file
```

Explanation:

- `printf "%s '"'"'", $1;` Print the first field, followed by a space and a quote (`'`)
- `for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i;` Print all of the following fields save the last one, each followed by a space.
- `print $NF "'"'"'"` Print the last field followed by a quote(`'`)

Note that `'"'"'"` is used to print just a single quote (`'`). An alternative is to specify the quote character on the command line as a variable:

```
awk -v qt="'" '{ printf "%s %s", $1, qt; for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i; print $NF qt }' file
```

Comment: This removes all space in front of the text

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this by taking advantage of the word-splitting involved in most shells like bash. To avoid ending up with an extra single quote in the final result, you can just remove it with sed. This will also trim any extra spaces before i, between i and j and after j.

`cat file.txt | sed "s/'//g" | while read i j; do echo "$i '$j'"; done`

Here, we'll pipe the first word into variable i, and the rest in j.

Comment: you should really provide more than just a code snippet. A little commentary explaining what the code does and how it solves the problem helps others learn and understand.

Comment: The `sed "s/'//g"` command to preemptively remove single quotes is - at least without explanation - distracting. Also, you should state that this solution trims leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -v q="'" '{ f1=$1; $1=""; print f1, q substr($0,2) q }' file
```

- Lets `awk` split each input line into fields by whitespace (the default behavior).
- `-v q="'"` defines awk variable `q` containing a single quote so as to make it easier to use a single quote inside the awk program, which is single-quoted as a whole.
- `f1=$1` saves the 1st field for later use.
- `$1==""` effectively removes the first field from the input line, leaving `$0`, which originally referred to the whole input line, to contain a space followed by the rest of the line (strictly speaking, the fields are re-concatenated using the output-field separator `OFS`, which defaults to a space; since the 1st field is now empty, the resulting `$0` starts with a single space followed by all remaining fields separated by a space each).
- `print f1, q substr($0,2) q` then prints the saved 1st field, followed by a space (`OFS`) due to `,`, followed by the remainder of the line (with the initial space stripped with `substr()`) enclosed in single quotes (`q`).

Note that this solution normalizes whitespace:

- leading and trailing whitespace is removed
- interior whitespace of length greater than 1 is compressed to a single space each.

Answer (score 0):

Since the post is tagged with `bash`, here is an all Bash solution that preserves leading white space.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    read -r f1 f2 <<<"$line"
    echo "${line/$f1 $f2/$f1 $'\''$f2$'\''}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
       113259740 'QA Test in progress'   
       219919630 'UAT Test in progress'
```

Comment: It works and is fine for smaller files, but note that processing large numbers of lines in pure `bash` tends to get really sloooow. Also, in bash 4+ the only chars. you need to quote are the `'` instances: `"${line/$f1 $f2/$f1 \'$f2\'}"`. Curiously, this will not work as expected in bash 3.x (most of the Linux world has moved on to bash 4+, but OSX is stuck with 3.x); a version that will work on both 3.x and 4+: `"${line/$f1 $f2/$f1 $'\''$f2$'\''}"`.

Comment: Yes, Bash is slower in many situations.  I've updated the post with your suggestion to make it compatible with 3.x and 4+.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{sub($2,v"&");sub($NF,"&"v)}1' v=\' file
       113259740 'QA Test in progress'
       219919630 'UAT Test in progress'
```

It does not change the formatting of the file.